# Delay jquery function until reaching a certain div (scrollTop?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow that I would like to delay it's start until you reached the top of the div. Currently we did this with an absolute pixel value, but this doesn't work in mobile. Is there a way to say "when reaching div 3, start this animation"?

What we currently have:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if($("body").scrollTop() === 500){
    $(window).off("scroll");
    // Code here
  }
}
```

I have mocked up a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj6xusa6/1/)** of the slide show as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would suggest you to get the current position of element with which you want to apply your conditions and compare those positions on **scroll** event..

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the body scroll has reached the div starts with `offset().top`

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if($("body").scrollTop() === $("#yourDivID").offset().top){
    $(window).off("scroll");
    // Code here
  }
}
```

this will work

> For Ref : **[Offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)**

Comment: I inputted this and it ended up breaking code, no animation ability, but also did not throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top position of your element like this :

```
var top = document.querySelector("div 3").getBoundingClientRect().top
```